# I want to make sh file that execute jar file directly in Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu

In Ubuntu 12.04 (Not Working)

I create a sh file and write the code.

```
  @echo off
  java -jar Program.jar
```

also allow the permission of execution.
But no action performed. While in windows it works fine.

In Windows 7 (Working)

I create a batch file and write the code.

```
@echo off
java -jar Program.jar
```

Please help what i am doing wrong.

Comment: UNIX shell scripts and Windows batch files are written in **different** languages.  Don't expect bat-isms to work in a shell script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu shell scripts can't use `@echo off` that's for DOS command scripts. You need something like,

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar Program.jar
```

The first line is known as the [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) (the `#!` is a kind of [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)).